# Redirect in form handler causing form to be submitted twice

Tags: hooks, forms

I have a front-end form and I'm using a POST handler in a plugin using the init hook. Basically, it's:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="mktinto-form" class="profile-form">
  <!-- form fields here -->
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="profile-form">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And the handler:

```
function vv_process_profile_forms() {
  if ( isset( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'profile-form' ) {

    // form processing code here

    $redirect_page = get_permalink( 586 );
    wp_redirect( $redirect_page ); exit;
  }
}
add_action( 'init','vv_process_profile_forms' );
```

The form is submitted and the page redirects to the next page in the process.

The form posts fine, the redirect happens, but the form handler actually runs twice. If I remove the redirect, it only runs once, like it should, but then, of course, it doesn't move to the next page. So it seems like the double posting is a result of the redirect, but I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I meant to answer this earlier. Turns out the problem was developer error (me!). I was using a javascript form handler that would process data and pass it on to the php form handler. Turns out that I was actually loading the .js file twice on the page. Kicked myself real hard for wasting the better part of a day figuring that out.

I had actually fixed it by unbinding the form submit event in the javascript, but then I found the root cause and no longer needed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it through Session. try

```
function vv_process_profile_forms() {
    session_start();

    if ( isset( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'profile-form' ) {

        if ( ! isset( $_SESSION['form-submit'] ) ) {

            // form processing code here

            $_SESSION['form-submit'] = 1;

            $redirect_page = get_permalink( 586 );
            wp_redirect( $redirect_page );
            exit;

        } else {

            unset( $_SESSION['form-submit'] );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'init','vv_process_profile_forms' );
```